# Why Video Tag is not working in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, video, tags

I am struggling with the video tag. Only for the IE browser. It is not working on any version of IE. [refer screenshot: IE11 video issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTbg2.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

i'm working with the video tag in IE11 it's working , this is an example for html check it out :

> video style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="4b8cca36-2d94-484f-bb69-269ac3ef38c7.mp4" crossorigin="use-credentials">

Comment: No, it's not working at my end. is it possible to you to share a live link. Which i can see in IE? That will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Already did R&D using this link. It showing black box with messages 'Aborted'.

Comment: which IE Version do you use ?

Comment: i am using IE 11.